# Can I retrieve pciklist values and update my record using force:recordData?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura

I am creating a Lightning component to update `Status__c` picklist in my object.

Using the [trailhead page](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/lightning_data_service/units/lightning_data_service_manipulate_records) I can use `lightning:forceData` tag to retrieve the record and display them in fields. What I don't know how to do is have it display it in a picklist and display all the available values in there.

```
  <force:recordData aura:id="recordLoader"
  recordId="{!v.recordId}"
  layoutType="FULL"
  targetRecord="{!v.record}"
  targetFields="{!v.simpleRecord}"
  targetError="{!v.recordError}"
  mode="EDIT"
  />

<div class="Record Details">
    <lightning:card iconName="action:edit" title="Update Library Status">
        <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small">
            <lightning:input label="Library Status" value="{!v.simpleRecord.Status__c}"/>
            <br/>
            <lightning:button label="Save" variant="brand" onclick="{!c.handleSaveRecord}" />
        </div>
    </lightning:card>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

*lightning:input* does not support rendering a select list. You can find more on what it supports on its [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_input.htm).

If you want to edit a record and to render picklist fields, you may like to use *lightning:recordEditForm* along with *lightning:inputField*. A sample component to update picklist field would look like:

```
<lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="recordViewForm"  recordId="xxxx" objectApiName="API Name of the Object">
    <div class="Record Details">
        <lightning:card iconName="action:edit" title="Update Library Status">
            <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small">
                <lightning:inputField fieldName="Status__c"/>
                <br/>
                <lightning:button label="Save" variant="brand" onclick="{!c.handleSaveRecord}" />
            </div>
        </lightning:card>
    </div>
</lightning:recordEditForm>
```

You can find more on respective documentation for [lightning:recordEditForm](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_recordEditForm.htm) and [lightning:inputField](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_inputField.htm).