# Picklists values and lookups for force:recordData

Tags: lightning, force-recorddata

Is there any option to render some input with picklist values in order to use it with force:recordData?
I know that lightning:recordEditForm with lightning:inputField can do this (see here: [Can I retrieve pciklist values and update my record using force:recordData?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/214819/can-i-retrieve-pciklist-values-and-update-my-record-using-forcerecorddata)), but to be honest it doesn't work very well. It is hard to maintain in the long term when we have to use it only to display values in "disabled" mode (in input fields, not as it is in lightning:outputField). Using recordEditForm it is not even possible to disable lookup field (sic!).
force:recordData seems to be the best solution, especially that it works on the same cached data together with other components and standard layouts  without refreshing a page.

**TLDR**: I'm looking for such solution as lightning:inputField (picklist) together with lightning:recordEditForm but working with force:recordData. The same for lookup field. Something working out-of-box and with possibility to disable the field (I'm pretty sure that they don't exist, I whish I was wrong).

Is there something like that?